# Using NLP to Extract Information from check-ins and Comments

Tags: python, apache-spark, nlp, recommendation-engine, bigdata

We're CS students and we're working on a recommendation system for our GP. 
Our data set contains users and the places they have visited, we want to use NLP to translate those places into activities.
ex. (Mall -> Shopping, Club -> Playing ...) and so on. 
and also if the users write down a comment we may know what kind of activity they are doing.

We're kinda lost at this point and wanna know from where should we start or what should we start searching for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As with most problems of this type, there are two routes:

**Hand Written**:

The lowest initial cost yet least scalable approach would be to hand define the actions associated with each location in your dataset and store them in a dictionary. If the number of unique locations is low, you could probably crank out all of the associated actions with little effort. Tasks-for-hire services like [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) could also be used (you would probably want to aggregate multiple answers for each location to filter out low quality associations).

**Machine Extracted**:

The other approach would be to use some NLP algorithm to learn/extract the appropriate location based on a large set of examples. If no satsifactory dataset exists then you would need to make your own (which is just as much work is the first approach). Once you have a corpus, you would need to do some Semantic Role Labeling, a good introduction can be found [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/22.pdf).